How to Resolve CORS Policy Block for Microsoft OAuth2 Authorization Request in Node.js and React App
I have an application with a NodeJS backend and a React frontend, and I want to implement Azure SSO for it. Since the frontend is served by the backend, users who want to log in to the application are redirected by the backend to the login page on the frontend. When users click on the relevant button on the login page, the Azure authentication page should open, and after login, they should be redirected back to my application. However, I am getting an error on the API side as shown below.
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={clientid}1&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Fauth%2Fcallback&response_mode=query&scope=https:%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default+offline_access' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/sso-login') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
my api code is
const params = new URLSearchParams({
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    response_type: 'code',
    redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI,
    response_mode: 'query',
    scope: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default offline_access'
  });

  res.redirect(`${authorizeUrl}?${params.toString()}`);

i created a simple nodejs app with same logic without frontend, it worked without problem.
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  const params = new URLSearchParams({
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    response_type: 'code',
    redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI,
    response_mode: 'query',
    scope: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default offline_access'
  });

  res.redirect(`${authorizeUrl}?${params.toString()}`);
});

app.get('/auth/callback', async (req, res) => {
  const { code } = req.query;

  if (!code) {
    return res.status(400).send('Authorization code not found.');
  }

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(tokenUrl, new URLSearchParams({
      client_id: CLIENT_ID,
      scope: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
      code,
      redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI,
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET
    }));

    const accessToken = response.data.access_token;
    res.send(`Access Token: ${accessToken}`);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(`Error exchanging code: ${error.message}`);
  }
});```
 


Seems like instead of following the redirect you’re trying to fetch it on the frontend. However, you haven’t added a [mre] of the frontend code that actually produces this error.

@osmnfdrcn Have you added cors in the backend code? Can you share it in the question?

@osmnfdrcn Can you provide your GitHub repo?

you need to add cors for the nodejs code

@osmnfdrcn Try this GitHub repository to fix the cors issue in the backend(nodejs). Frontend output.

@osmnfdrcn Backend output.

I fixed the issue by adding CORS to the backend (Node.js) code. Users who want to log in to the application are now successfully redirected by the backend to the login page on the frontend, and the access token is retrieved.
Here is the complete code in this GitHub repository.
backend/index.js :
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const cors = require('cors');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
const tokenUrl = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token`;

app.get('/api/auth/sso-login', (req, res) => {
  const params = new URLSearchParams({
    client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    response_type: 'code',
    redirect_uri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI,
    response_mode: 'query',
    scope: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default offline_access',
  });

  const loginUrl = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?${params.toString()}`;
  res.redirect(loginUrl);
});

app.post('/api/auth/exchange-token', async (req, res) => {
  const { code } = req.body;
  if (!code) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Authorization code not provided' });
  }
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(tokenUrl, new URLSearchParams({
      client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      scope: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
      code,
      redirect_uri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI,
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    }));
    const accessToken = response.data.access_token;
    res.json({ accessToken });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: `Error exchanging code: ${error.message}` });
  }
});

const PORT = 4000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Backend running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

.env :
CLIENT_ID=<Client_ID>
CLIENT_SECRET=<Client_Secret>
TENANT_ID=<tenant_ID>
REDIRECT_URI=http://localhost:3000/auth/callback

frontend/Login.js :
import React from 'react';

const Login = () => {
  const handleLogin = () => {
    window.location.href = `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/api/auth/sso-login`;
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Login Page</h2>
      <button onClick={handleLogin}>Login with Azure</button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Login;

frontend/.env :
REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID=<client_ID>
REACT_APP_TENANT_ID=<tenant_ID>
REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URI=http://localhost:3000/auth/callback
REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL=http://localhost:4000

I have added the below URL in the Azure AD app's redirect URI under Web as shown below.
http://localhost:3000/auth/callback


backend Output :
I successfully ran the backend (Node.js) application. When I opened the URL below in the browser, it redirected me to the login page, and I logged in with my account as shown below:
http://localhost:4000/api/auth/sso-login


After logging in, I received the authorization code as shown below:

I copied the authorization code and used it in the POST request, as shown below.

I sent a POST request with the authorization_code and received the access token as shown below.
http://localhost:4000/api/auth/exchange-token

{
  "code": "<authorization_code>"
}


frontend Output :
I successfully ran the frontend (React.js) application and logged in using the Login with Azure button.


After logging in, I retrieved the access token as shown below.

